# Webpack and Express - Critical Dependencies Warning

Tags: express, webpack

I have the following `webpack.config.ts`:

```
var webpack = require( 'webpack' );
var path = require( 'path' );

module.exports = {

  entry: [
    './api/bin/www.ts'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, './dist/api' ),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '', '.js', '.ts' ]
  },
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};
```

When I run webpack I get a warning about a dependency:

```
WARNING in ./~/express/lib/view.js
Critical dependencies:
78:29-56 the request of a dependency is an expression
@ ./~/express/lib/view.js 78:29-56
```

The express server I start with this is no more than a `Hello World` example and **functions as should** but I am concerned about this warning.

My googlefu hasn't revealed any passable solutions. I have seen one particular instance of this problem but the solutions were to bypass the warning by not showing it.

Comment: can you include the code of your view.js?

Comment: try with webpack-node-externals plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals

Comment: @leo that isnt a file in my repo, it is just included through express I think when I di `import * from express`

Comment: I'm really confused.  The OP says the file is "webpack.config.*ts*" (emphasis mine), but everything else I see says this should be a .js file, and indeed its syntax seems to be more consistent with JavaScript files.  Is this just a typo?

Comment: @Everettss too bad you didn't provide that tip as an answer... lol.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use webpack-node-externals.

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

{
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals

Comment: This removed my error but some how it is not generating chunk files - 
`Webpack: output server.0.chunk.js, 
Webpack: output server.1.chunk.js, 
Webpack: output server.2.chunk.js, 
Webpack: output server.3.chunk.js`

Comment: How can I have import and require alongside?

Comment: @mohit, maybe you forgot about the round brackets of nodeExternal, like I did :): external: [nodeExternal()]

Answer (score 15):

For those that only need to remove the express due to the view lib as mentioned here you can also explicitly target express in externals from your webpack config.

`externals: [{ 'express': { commonjs: 'express' } }]`

Comment: Nice solution. In my case I needed to add also `output: {...clientOutput, libraryTarget: 'commonjs'},` to my webpack.config to avoid module.exports = undefined in my bundle (according to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2030)

Answer (score 3):

My warning only got fixed with:

```
module.exports =
{
    target: 'node',
    externals: {
        "express": "require('express')"
    }
}
```

Comment: This will require node_modules being installed.

Comment: @Townsheriff it is must have, probably express can not work bundled

Answer (score 1):

Instead of excluding all of the npm dependencies to be bundled with nodeExternals you can also exclude only express by natively requiring it by replacing

```js
import express from 'express';
// Or
const express = require('express');
```

To

```js
const express = __non_webpack_require__('express');
```

That will suppress the warning caused by express